# Input in a prompt for an answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, prompt

I am making a javascript game a say what you see, and so far i have this code

```
function change(name, image) {
    document.images[name].src=image+".jpg";
}

<p>What is this an image of? </p>

<img src="image1.jpg" name="image1">


<form name=question1>

<input type=button value="What is your answer" 
onClick="

  s=prompt('Enter your answer','answer');

  alert('Dog '+s+'!')">

</form>
```

I have managed too get the image to load, and to explain the game, but I don't know how to make the prompt work correctly so they input an answer and I have to tell them if it is correct or not. Would this be some sort of if statement? I have not a lot of experience in java script and would enjoy any solutions thanks

Comment: Yes, it would be some sort of if statement. You need to have some sort of identifier with that image to let the javascript know if the user has entered the correct image

Answer (score 1):

This code should provide what you are looking for. I did change your html a bit as it was slightly messy.

Check out this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5wzmkfwx/3/

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

This function is triggered when the user clicks the button, asking what the image is. If the correct answer is given it will alert the user with a correct answer message. If the answer is incorrect it will bypass the `if` statement and reach the `else` statement and be executed there, informing the user of the correct answer.

```
 function checkAnswer(){
    prompt('What animal is in the image?')
    if('dog'){
        alert('Well Done. Correct answer')
    }
    else{
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a dog')
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<p>What is this an image of? </p>
<img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/earliest-dogs-660x433-130306-akita-660x433.jpg" class="image1">

<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Answer</button>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for, and if not I can change accordingly.

Comment: your awnser was correct however you forgot to assign the result to a variable here is an fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/5wzmkfwx/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have this so far, but I don't know how to add a scoring system will this be some sort of variable? I want it too say they have scored 1 for correct answer or 0 for incorrect answer, and at the end it says you have scored 5 or 4 or whatever they scored!

```
document.write("This is a type what you see game, the objective of the game is to answer what you see on screen, by typing into the box, a correct answer will be worth 2 points, and incorrect answer will be worth 0 points, best of luck!")

function checkAnswer(){

   a= prompt('What animal is in the image?');

    if(a=='dog'){

        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');

    }

    else{

        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a dog');
    }

}


function checkAnswer2(){

   b= prompt('What animal is in the image?');

    if(b=='hamster'){

        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');

    }

    else{

        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a hamster');

    }

}


function checkAnswer3(){

   c= prompt('What animal is in the image?');

    if(c=='hedgehog'){

        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');

    }

    else{

        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a hedgehog');

    }

}


function checkAnswer4(){

   d= prompt('What animal is in the image?');

    if(d=='turtle'){

        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');

    }
    else{
        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a turtle');

    }


}


function checkAnswer5(){

   e= prompt('What animal is in the image?');

    if(e=='turtle'){

        alert('Well Done. Correct answer');

    }

    else{

        alert('Sorry, incorrect, it is a turtle');

    }

}
```

What is this an image of?

Answer

What is this an image of?

Answer

What is this an image of?

Answer

What is this an image of?

Answer

p>What is this an image of?

Answer